Why is localhost not connecting to my project
(node:8428) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
[Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink 'C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MY PROJECTS\padding-officing-ui.next\server\app'] {
errno: -4071,
code: 'EINVAL',
syscall: 'readlink',
path: 'C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MY PROJECTS\padding-officing-ui\.next\server\app'
}
i tried to run dev and i expect the localhost to show my workings but the localhost refused to connect

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
